# Couldn't execute 'show events' 15777

Tags: mysql

After spending days for looking for a solution, I'm taking my chance here. I have a MySQL server that I try to backup with the following command :

```
mysqldump -p --all-databases --allow-keywords --master-data --events --single-transaction 
   -u root > /root/mysqldump.sql
```

When I'm doing this, I have this answer :

> mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show events': Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start (1577).

I have try to do a `mysql_upgrade -u root -h localhost -p --verbose --force` everything look OK but the mysqldump still not working with the same error.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Don't know much about the error message, but from reading it, it sounds like your database server is corrupted in some way.

Comment: I agree, but the problem is that I do not know how I can fix it since mysql_upgrade does not work. A suggestion ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the other suggestions in the manual to try and repair the damaged tables? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html. Alternatively can you restore the server from a recent (known good) backup? Do you know when this problem started? Can you attribute it to some specific event or change to the system?

Comment: Yes I have try to rebuild the database according to this link. But the problem are not solve. So I used the command without the "events" attribute and it worked

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but the mysql_dump worked fine despite those warnings. I use Mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian.

Your command fixed the error:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -h localhost -p --verbose --force
```

Update: I had the same error after migrating the server to a new mashine, I guess, because I used rsync for the database files and no mysqldump. The command also fixed the error again on Debian stretch with Mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB